# How can I attach a USB microphone to a Breakout-board using ADC Ports?

Tags: usb, adc, microphone, breakout

I am almost a total noobie to electrical engineering and I bought a programmable Drone called "PlutoX" from [here](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/plutox-kit-unbreakable-nanodrone-10-diy-projects/x/19417637).
I am currently trying to attach a **USB microphone like this:** [image: like this]

to the so called "X-Breakout board" delivered by the drone manufacturers.

My question is... how can I **attach the usb microphone** mentioned above to the ADC Ports on the Breakout board? Here's an image: [image]

I've circled the ADC Ports in red. Through some recherche I was able to find out that the slot on the very bottom of the ADC Ports is the Pin13 (for coding purposes), where I have to attach the microphone to. Unfortunately I don't know which kind of wire I need for this or even which kinds of wires exist.

I am pretty sure that I will need some kind of adapter to set up a connection between the usb microphone and a wire which is connected to the Breakout board.

I am very thankful for your help!

Comment: You simply cannot.  You could maybe gut it for the element but simpler just to buy one.  What do you hope to accomplish with a microphone anyway?

Comment: You will need an analog microphone or microphone capsule.  That USB microphone can only be used with a USB port.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am trying to connect a microphone to the Breakout board which is connected to the drone to detect voice and perform speech recognition. The Breakout board is connected via BUS to the drone.

Comment: That's not going to work either.  Certainly not in an MCU.  How about you first try running various existing voice recognition systems with a drone tied on top of them and the rotors running so that they are subject to all of its acoustical noise?  If it actually worked, maybe you could do something like strap that alexa voice remote to your drone...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an XY problem.  The real issues to be solved are voice recognition on a flying platform with prop noise, trying to connect a USB microphone to the existing MCU will not aid that goal.

Comment: I've had an idea how to fix this... but then it's totally off-topic. I am gonna connect the drone as well as a raspberry pi (with the usb microphone) to the same WiFi network. The raspberry pi performs speech recognition and sends the data via WiFi to the drone. I am not an expert so my ideas are mostly experimental and probably don't always work. @ChrisStratton

Comment: @Frenggie, there are voice recognition modules available .... you could even use an Arduino to send the commands ... https://1sheeld.com/top-5-arduino-voice-control-modules/

Comment: @Frenggie start with voice recognition on any computer that's fast enough and that you are used to using for software development: probably your laptop! If it works, move it to a raspberry pi (as  long as that's still fast enough). If you can make it work with the limited constraints of the MCU on the drone controller (hint: um, no.), then you can move it to that, alternatively. But never start developing something complex on an embedded system if you've got the choice to first make it work on a PC-style computer. Still very confusing: why would you even want the drone itself to have a mic?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I thought it was a cool idea to control the drone via mic. but I forgot about the fact that I am a bit doodoo and the propellers are too loud, so they would disturb the whole process.

Comment: @Frenggie most importantly, I'd expect a drone not to necessarily be close to the mouth of the person controlling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The USB "Microphone" is actually a microphone, an amplifier, analog filtering, an ADC of its own, a bit of digital signal processing and a microcontroller that speaks the rather complex USB protocol, probably all in one chip (aside from the actual microphone).

There's no analog signal coming out anywhere of that thing.

You need to use an analog microphone, add your own amplifier and anti-aliasing filter before connecting it to your microcontroller's ADC.

Comment: How could I add the amplifier and anti-aliasing filter for such an analog microphone on my own? And how could I attach an analog microphone like [this](https://www.digikey.de/product-detail/de/sparkfun-electronics/BOB-12758/1568-1472-ND/6592307?utm_adgroup=Dev+Boards+and+Kits&mkwid=sST4l7jjX&pcrid=218211101233&pkw=&pmt=&pdv=c&productid=6592307&slid=&gclid=CjwKCAjw4ZTqBRBZEiwAHHxpfrY8buivtIEx9GlmsIqoWw2WEPm_OeiDBZPgodWXfG72JntfaD4KaBoCUnUQAvD_BwE) to the ADC Port?

Comment: I think this can be easily answered by searching for something like "connect microphone to ADC", for example on this site.

Comment: Yeah... I think so. Thank you!